# highlight next 3 days from hover date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I get `DatePicker` to highlight the hovered date and the next 3 days before clicking on it?

I have browsed the web and only found [this example](http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/) for jCal that does exactly what I'm looking for, but I need an example of the code for JQuery datepicker.

Here is my working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d7kPc/2/. What I need is if you mouseover Friday it then highlights the following Saturday, Sunday and Monday and the same logic for mouseover on Monday it then highlights the following Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

Comment: What code have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hope that I got you right...  My approach would be...

```
$(".element").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css("background", "red").next().css("background", "red").next().css("background", "red").next().css("background", "red");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background", "white").next().css("background", "white").next().css("background", "white").next().css("background", "white");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the working  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6MV/6/) here what you exactly want and imprement it to your code .

```
$('#jCalTarget').jCal({
    day:            new Date(),
    days:           3,
    showMonths:     2,
    monthSelect:    true,
    });
```

Thanks

Udit Bhardwaj

Comment: Yes this is exactly what im after but is it simple mod to get it working with jquery datepicker?

Comment: depends on how you implement it . if you use that i have done in the Fiddle it would be a longer code , i done it with the provided link by you . Ok i will find some thing useful to you as i get tym . THank you

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect there are some properties and attributes .